# Postgres replace operation when finds None

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field that I want to cast as json but the keys are single quoted instead of double quoted:

```
{'id': 12249, 'value': 'any string'}
{'id': 12232, 'value': 'other thing'}
```

I am using this:

```
select replace(column,'''','"')::jsonb as columnj from table
```

The code above works fine until it finds a row with `None` like this:

```
{'id': None, 'value': None}
```

How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to keep the *None*-valued rows, you can add quotes to *None* values using a nested `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(json_str,'''','"'), 
               'None', 
               '"None"')                   ::JSONB AS columnj 
FROM tab
```

If instead you don't want to include in the json those rows, which have the `None` value, then you can just filter them out:

```
SELECT REPLACE(json_str,'''','"')::JSONB AS columnj 
FROM tab
WHERE json_str NOT LIKE '%None%';
```

Check the demo of both solutions [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4byykV2bpE3orzacrs4uj/0).